# Multiple Emails generated by Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, cfmail

We just installed Lucee 5.3.2.77 that uses Apache Tomcat/9.0.20 and AdoptOpenJdk 11.0.3 64 bit.

I also have an existing application that is currently running in a DMZ on

- ColdFusion 11 Standard edition in production
- ColdFusion 11 Enterprise on QA and local.

We also have another Lucee Server running Lucee 5.3.1.102 and Oracle Java 1.8.0_181, on which we are doing our testing and changes.

On all of the boxes, when an email is generated, it only generates the email once. However, on the new Lucee box with OpenJDK, the email is generated and a .tsk file is created in this folder

```
c:$\inetpub\wwwroot\webdir\sitename\WEB-INF\lucee\remote-client\open
```

The problem is the file stays there. The next time an email task is run another .tsk file is created and both emails are sent. Wash, rinse, repeat. So if 3 emails are generated, then

- The first person will receive 3 emails
- The second, 2 emails
- The third, 1 email.

For testing, we generated the first email, waited a few minutes. Generated a second, waited. Then generated a third. Has anyone come across this?

I added server="mail server" to the cfmail tag

```
<cfmail from="appointments@xyz.com" to="<twright@xyz.com>" 
    subject="Appointment Test" type="HTML" server="<mail.xyz.com>">
<html>
<head><title>Appointment Test</Title>
</head>
<body>
Your appointment has been scheduled at TEST
Number: 123456
Net Weight: 25000
Appointment Date: 08/16/2019
Appointment Time: 1800
Appointment Number: 111111111
</body>
</html>
</cfmail>
```

So I would expect 1 email to be sent when executed. In this case, as stated above, each time the page is called it generates the email and then resends for all the others in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lucee\remote-client\open` folder. If it matters, the email is being sent through Office 365.

Comment: Never had this before and you might be more likely to get an answer over at dev.lucee.org

Comment: I had done that as well .,thanks

Comment: Are you saying this only occurs on Lucee 5.3.2.77 - but *not* on 5.3.1.102?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the lucee admin mail services - Mail
If the Spool enable is checked, uncheck it and update.

Delete any files in the open folder.